# Matlab 2012b desktop - reactivating the old "retro style" desktop?

Tags: matlab

This has the clear potential of ending up in a flame war, but anyway, I give it a try ... there is not any **definitive** answer out there (as yet).

On one of my machines, I literally was switched/upgraded to Matlab 2012b. It's a nice new pretty shiny desktop, ok. But I am very much used to the old crappy one, for a good number of reasons. Has anyone of you found a specific way (options, hacking config files, whatever) in order to regain the old Matlab desktop - primarily the old menus (file, edit, ...) and buttons of the editor window (the debugging stuff, like executing a cell)?

**EDIT (1)**: The interface of the figure-window is still the same as before, with menus etc., no matter whether it is docked or not. That's interesting, there is still a part of the old desktop there ...

Comment: Give in to the future now, save yourself a world of pain and frustration.  Through how many upgrades will you cling to the old ways, at each new launch finding it ever more difficult to keep both feet in the past ?  One day you'll give in, no longer prepared to waste time degrading the UI, it might as well be today.

Comment: My suggestion is to use this as an opportunity to really learn the keyboard shortcuts, and stop using the menus/toolbars/ribbon/toolstrip at all. Especially for debugging and executing cells, it's way faster than either the new or the old desktop. Try customizing the shortcuts from the Preferences, to make sure the ones you most need are set to easily remembered things.

Comment: Frustration ... the KDE-3-to-4-transition already turned me into a skilled bash-user. It's ironic, but most "progress" within the GUIs makes me going back in "history" even more. Maybe the next logical step is learning "vi" (1970s, here I come) and kicking the Matlab desktop all together. Then, maybe, this is going to be a peaceful, stable & long-term solution, which makes my life easier ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of good comments suggesting alternatives to what you originally asked, but the direct answer to your question is no - as far as I'm aware, it's not possible to get the old desktop back.

Comment: As far as I can tell, unfortunately, you are right. There is not any option or hack, and it is not even intended to exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "old version" you want - you can start MATLAB in a very sparse manner using

matlab -nojvm -nodesktop

in both Windows and Linux.  The -nojvm command disables a lot of things you probably want, so

matlab -nodesktop

Is probably the easiest middle ground, unless your JVM is giving you fits.  Note: this is a really, really sparse UI.  I think they used to call it "Cleve Mode" at the Mathworks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleve_Moler)

But you probably want a newer version than what this gives you; what specific commands do you want?  As others above have mentioned, executing a cell, for example, should never be done by point-and-click; its a great keyboard short-cut now - "ctrl-enter"; there's really 
no reason to be clicking around in the "ribbon" or "menus" anymore.

Comment: nojvm & nodesktop ... I am already doing this a lot. My question is more, whether it is possible to get the old desktop back. It is kind of a yes/no question.